# Are there any good videos to learn programming basics which are required to learn javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, programming-languages, frontend

Are there any good video to learn programming basics which are required to learn JavaScript, then jQuery later. for the person who is already having good command over xhtml and css ? future aim is not to learn any server-side language, php, asp.net, ruby ,etc. just pure and advanced javascript/jQuery.

Video for absolute programming beginner, who does not know what 'string', variable, function etc... are

Please only give links of videos.

Comment: When I was young, we learned programming from these things called "books".  You might have heard of them.

Comment: @Paul Tomblin - in this day and age, we have these new fangled contraptions called com-puters, which can show you these "screen-casts" ;)

Comment: @metal-gear-solid - Out of curiosity, how did you get to nearly 8k rep on SO w/o knowing what a string or function are?

Comment: I feel like such an old man for preferring books. But really, having my own customizable internal narrator makes reading much more enjoyable. I can get [Morgan Freeman](http://xkcd.com/462/) to teach me, and if I get bored of him, I can easily switch to Johnny Depp (in his Mad Hatter voice)! It certainly beats a man who snorts every few seconds (coincidentally, is it just me, or does every person who records a screen cast have an uncontrollable snorting tick?).

Comment: @Oded, you mean so you have to go through the material at somebody else's idea of the correct pacing rather than spending more time on the things you think you need to spend more time on and going quickly through the bits that seem obvious?  I'm not seeing the allure, myself.

Comment: @Ender, I'm guessing he wants to teach someone else.

Comment: I'm learning very quickly that the best way to learn is to start making mistakes. I know you're looking for videos, but the harsh reality is that you need to read - a lot. Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript Read the entire site. Start programming. I found the "re-introduction to javascript" very helpful.

Comment: @ender - my most point are coming from my questions. I'm not claiming I'm an expert but i can't stop people who are voting to question. Do you mean if a person don't know about string or function, can't get 8k rep on SO?

Comment: @Paul Tomblin - Just poking some fun at your "When I was young"... I too learn best from books and from doing (and taking my own time and pace at it).

Answer (score 4):

For the absolute basics, I've always enjoyed the [Karel the Robot series](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkMDCCdjyW8) put out by Stanford University. It's a series of lectures from an introductory programming course. The language used in the class is Java, but the ideas presented are universal. If one really is an absolute beginner, it's a great tool.

**Edit:** The question changed after I posted this answer, so it's not really relevant to the new question, but helpful nonetheless =)

Comment: Listening to this video, it actually sounds like this might be exactly what metal-gear-solid is looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the link! This is the whole CS106A Stanford class. There are more classes they have available on youtube as well. This should certainly be the accepted answer. The Karel the Robot method of teaching programming concepts is genius. It provides a limited scope of things to learn, so you can just focus on basic programming principles while still learning about functions, loops, etc.

Answer (score 1):

These might help you:

http://blog.themeforest.net/screencasts/jquery-for-absolute-beginners-video-series/

**UPDATE**

This article links to a few videos of a class on learning JavaScript:

http://www.catonmat.net/blog/learning-javascript-programming-language-through-video-lectures/

However, to be frank, it sounds like what you made need is a class or a book specifically designed to teach programming.  If you are lacking understanding of such fundamentals as strings and functions, a simple video tutorial is unlikely to be sufficient.

Comment: I've seen those. those are not for beginners.

Comment: @Oded - beginner who don't know what is the mean of "string" and variable, function etc.

Comment: @metal-gear-solid - how about updating your question then, adding the detail of "absolute programming beginner, who does not know what 'string', variable, function etc... are".

Comment: @Ender - Thanks for second link. I'm already about that also. but that are also not for absolute beginner.

Comment: I agree those aren't for absolute (programming) beginners, but they helped me. Thank you.